# el codigo de mi carrito me marca un error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

estoy trabajando en un carrito de abarrotes y al momento que se quiero cambiar la cantidad de los productos, no lo hace, ademas se tiene que actualizar el subtotal y el total, pero ninguno cambia
sus limites deben de ser as de 1 y menos de 10 articulos, y por ejemplo si quiero 3 productos se tendria que ingresar en la cantidad y cambiar automaticamente el subtotal del producto y el total de todos los productos

en donde me marca el error es en este codigo

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="<?php echo $cantidad;?>" 
size="5" id="cantidad_<?php echo $_id?>" onchange="actualizaCantidad(this.value, <?php echo $_id; ?>)">
```

mi codigo de carrito es este:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
require 'database.php';
$db= new Database(); //instanciamos a la clase de la carpeta condig/database
$con=$db->conectar();
$productos=isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos']) ? $_SESSION['carrito']['productos']:null; //validamos si existe una variable de sesion, e caso de que no exista se le pone null
//print_r($_SESSION);
$lista_carrito=array();
if ($productos != null){
    foreach($productos as $clave => $cantidad){
        $sql=$con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, descripcion, precio, descuento, $cantidad AS cantidad FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1");
        $sql->execute([$clave]); 
        $lista_carrito[]=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        /*$sql-- con esto creamos consultas preparadas*/
        /*$sql->execute()  con esto la variable se ejecuta, una vez que se ejecuta se trae al resultado*/
        /* $resulado--estamos llamando a todos los productos que esten en la tabla, idicamos que los traiga mediante PDO::FETCH_ASSOC-->asocia mediante el nombre de cada columna*/        
    }
}
//session_destroy();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tienda online</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <div class="navbar navbar-espand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <strong>Tienda</strong>
                <div>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <a href="carrito.php" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Carrito<span id="num_cart" class="badge bg-secondary"><?php echo $num_cart;?></span>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--contenido-->
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Productos</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Subtotal</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php  if($lista_carrito==null){
                            echo '<tr><td colspan=5 class="text-center"><b>Lista vacia agregelee</b></td></tr>';
                            }else{ $total=0;
                                   foreach($lista_carrito as $producto){
                                    $_id=$producto['id'];
                                    $nombre=$producto['nombre'];
                                    $precio=$producto['precio'];
                                    $descuento=$producto['descuento'];
                                    $precio_desc=$precio-(($precio*$descuento)/100);
                                    $subtotal=$cantidad*$precio_desc;
                                    $total +=$subtotal;
                                    ?>
                            
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $nombre ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo MONEDA. number_format($precio_desc,2,'.',','); ?></td>
                            <td>
                                 <input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="<?php echo $cantidad;?>" 
                                 size="5" id="cantidad_<?php echo $_id?>" onchange="actualizaCantidad(this.value, <?php echo $_id; ?>)"><!-- valor que va a tener el input -->
                                </td>
                            <td> 
                                <div id="subtotal_<?php echo $_id ?>" name="subtotal[]"><?php echo MONEDA. number_format($subtotal,2,'.',','); ?></div>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="#" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-bs-id="<?php $_id ?>" data-bs-toogle="modal" data-bs-target="eliminaModal">Eliminar</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <tr> 
                            <td colspan="3"></td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <p class="h3" id=total><?php echo MONEDA .number_format($total,2,'.',',') ?></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php }?>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-7 g-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Realizar pago</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function actualizaCantidad(cantidad,id){
            //api fech que proporcina javaScript
            let url='actualizarCarrito.php'
            let formData = new FormData() //ayuda a mandar los parametros por metodo post
            formData.append('action','agregar')
            formData.append('id',id)
            formData.append('cantidad',cantidad)
            fetch(url,{
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                mode: 'cors'
            }).then(response=> response.json())
            .then(data=> {
                if(data.ok){

                    let divsuntotal= document.getElementById('subtotal_'+id)
                    divsuntotal.innerHTML=data.sub
                
                }
            })

            }
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

el codigo  'config.php':

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
require 'config/database.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])){

    $action=$_POST['action'];
    $id=isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:0;// validacion para saber si existeel id entonces recibe el id por post si no existe entonces asignale un 0

    if($action=='agregar'){//si la funcion agregar
        //recibe la cantidad que va a agregar
        $cantidad=isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['cantidad']:0;
        $respuesta=agregar($id,$cantidad);
        if($respuesta>0){//si respuesta es mayor a cero significa que si encontro informacion y hay datos para regresar
            $datos['ok']=true;

        }else{
            $datos['ok']=false;
        }
        //creamps otra validacion de datos
        $datos['sub']= MONEDA . number_format($respuesta,2,'.',',');
    }else{
        $datos['ok']=false;
    }
}else{
    $datos['ok']=false;
    //si no llega el action retornamos false
}
echo json_encode($datos);//regresa la peticion
function agregar($id,$cantidad){//recibe el id y la cantidad
    //le indicamos que res es igual a =0
    $res=0;
    //hacemos validacion que el id sa mayor a 0
    if($id > 0 && $cantidad>0 && is_numeric(($cantidad))){ //is_numeric es para que la cantidad se haga numerica
        //validamos si existe el id de producto en la variable de session
        if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id])){//[]--> se les conoce como indice
            $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id]=$cantidad;

            $db= new Database();
            $con =$db->conectar();
            $sql=$con->prepare("SELECT precio,descuento FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1 LIMIT 1");
            $sql->execute([$id]); 
            $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $precio=$row['precio'];
            $descuento=$row['descuento'];
            $precio_desc=$precio- (($precio * $descuento)/100);
            $res=$cantidad*$precio_desc;

            return $res;
        }

    }else{
        return $res;
    }

}
?>
```

ya intente de todo pero no me sale, es para un proyecto de mi escuela, y mi profesora no me explica cual podria ser solucion, porfavor ayudenme:(

Comment: "Me marca un error" no da nada de información.. qué error te marca??

Comment: me marca estos errores Warning: A non-numeric value encountered i
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool